# How to insert values in a specific position an empty vector

Tags: c++, function, vector, constructor

How to insert an item in a specific position of std::vector not initialized and diplay it?

The class is called Inventory and the vector has a specific size
The issue is that the item is not added to the vector

```cpp
explicit Inventory::Inventory(int max = 10) : maxDim(max) {
        items.reserve(maxDim);
    };

void Inventory::insert(T* item, int pos) {
    if(pos >= 0 && pos < maxDim) {
        items[pos] = item;
    }else{
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid insertion");
    }
};
void Inventory::print() const {
   for(const auto& item : items) {
         if(item != nullptr)
            item->print();
   }
};
```

In main.cpp

```
inventory.insert(&robot1, 1);
inventory.print();
```

Output is empty

Comment: Change `reserve` to `resize`. After calling `reserve` the `vector` owns raw memory for N items, but it still doesn't actually contain any items. `resize` will resize it so it actually contains `N` items, so when you index into it, and overwrite an item, you'll get meaningful results. Also note that the `if` statement in `Inventory::insert` is nearly identical to using `items.at(pos) = item;` (except that using `at` would have caught this problem for you).

Comment: If there is an element at position N in a vector, then there are also elements at positions 0, 1, 2, ..., N-2, N-1. On the other hand, an empty vector has no elements. So the only position you can add an element to an empty vector is 0.

Comment: Did you try catching the exception? Catch and print error message. Also do you know about `vector::at()`? Size of vector can be retirved very easily with `size()` rather than keeping your own size information in `maxDim`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two possibilities, depending on what you're going for.  As others have mentioned, `reserve()` sets the capacity of the vector but not its logical size, while `resize()` changes the length of the vector.  If it's okay in your application to allocate all indices up to some max, then the other answer will work for you.

If you want a "sparse vector", where only a few elements exist, however, you may want to consider a map instead of a vector, as in:

```
<typename T>
class Inventory {
  std::map<int, T*> items;

public:
  void insert( T* item, int pos ) {
     auto it = items.find(pos);
     if( it != items.end() ) {
       it->second = item;
     } else {
       items.emplace( pos, item );
     }
  }

  void print() const {
    for( const auto& item : items ) {
       item->print();
    }
  }
};
```

There is no need for range checking using a map.  Regardless of which container you use, I'd consider using a smart pointer if the items are to be owned by the `Inventory`.

Answer (score 2):

The class template `std::vector` is a sequential container. So it means that a vector has as many positions as there are elements in the vector.

There are two approaches to your problem and the both are based on the method `resize`.

You could initially set the required size (the number of positions) of the vector like

```
explicit Inventory::Inventory(int max = 10) : maxDim(max) {
        items.resize(maxDim);
    }
```

Or when an element is added to the vector you could write

```
void Inventory::insert(T* item, int pos) {
    if(pos >= 0 && pos < maxDim) {
        if ( items.size() < pos + 1 ) items.resize( pos + 1 );
        items[pos] = item;
    }else{
        throw std::out_of_range("Invalid insertion");
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that using semicolons after method definitions is redundant.